# Generalized Mean Inequality with STD

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, inequality, standard-deviation, means

I am looking for a formal proof shows that for any $x\&y \geq 0$ and $\alpha > 1$,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i ^\alpha \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i ^\alpha
\end{equation}

where $STD(x_1...x_i) \geq STD(y_1...y_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$

I think I should use Generalized Mean Inequality but I don't know how because in GMI for any $s \geq 0$ and $\alpha > 1$,

\begin{equation}
(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_i^\alpha) \geq (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_i)^\alpha
\end{equation}

It can derives from the fact that since RHS has $STD = 0$ (we can say that we have $n$ numbers with the same value) but I think it is not a proof for this problem since I want to put it in an academic paper and also this inequality only shows a special case when $STD = 0$

Thanks

Comment: What is $STD()$?

Comment: Standard Deviation of $x_1$ to $x_i$

Comment: For each $i $? Or do you have $i$ random variables $x_k$, total (does not look from the sums which imply $n$ of $x_i$ and similarly for $y$? Are there othe assumptions (eg on independence of $x_i$s)?

Comment: A simple example: $x_1 = 0.1, x_2 = 0.5, x_3 = 0.9, y_1 = 0.4, y_2 = 0.5, y_3 = 0.6, \alpha = 2$ also $sum_x = sum_y = 1.5$ since $STD(x_i s) > STD(y_i s)$ then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i ^\alpha \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i ^\alpha$ holds. The number of $x$s and $y$s is equal and also sum of $x$s and $y$s equal too. $x$s and $y$s could be any number greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: O.K it seems that you are calculating the STD of the 'sample' $x_1\dots x_n$ (where the 'mean' used is the mean of this sample). So this gives another inequality with certain sums involving $x_i,y_i$s?

Comment: So, in other words, $\mathbb{D}^2X\geq \mathbb{D}^2Y$ and $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}Y$ implies $\mathbb{E}X^\alpha\geq\mathbb{E}Y^\alpha$

Comment: @AnyAD The means and also sums of two samples are equal but the STD could be different and results in different values for sum and also mean of each number to the power alpha.

Comment: @Jakobian so is it possible to easily proof it or it's hard?